# Zweideutige Aussage eindeutig machen

Tags: style

»Jemandem die Freude nehmen« heißt so viel wie ihm die Freude zu verderben. Genau hiervon sprach er aber *nicht*, der Schnapsbrenner im Fernsehen, der sagte:

> Freude zu nehmen und zu geben ist das Schönste im Leben.

Ein Fall von unfreiwilliger Komik.
Durch welche Umformulierung lässt sich der Satz eindeutig machen?
Oder anders: Was hätte der Schnapsbrenner eigentlich sagen sollen?

Comment: Was *wollte* er denn sagen?

Comment: Gibt es dazu eine Quelle, die man sich anhören kann? Könnte es sein, dass es "Die Freude, zu nehmen und zu geben, ist das Schönste im Leben"? Die Worte "geben" und "Leben" bilden einen Reim, daher vielleicht "nehmen und geben" anstatt des üblichen "geben und nehmen".

Comment: @PaulFrost: Meines Wissens wurde der Satz genau so gesagt, wie er in der Frage steht. Welche Sendung es war, weiß ich leider nicht mehr, das Gleiche gilt für Datum und Sender.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anstelle von

> Freude *zu nehmen* und zu geben ist das Schönste im Leben.

hätte er zum Beispiel einen der folgenden Sätze sagen können:

> - Freude *anzunehmen* und zu geben ist das Schönste im Leben.
> - Freude *zu empfangen* und zu geben ist das Schönste im Leben.

Comment: +1 for "empfangen"

Answer (score 2):

Der Fachbegriff für einen solchen "Versprecher" lautet [Stilblüte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stilbl%C3%BCte)

Statt *nehmen* schlage ich *bekommen* oder *erhalten* vor.

_Freude zu erhalten/bekommen und zu geben ist das Schönste im Leben.

Das klingt allerdings ein bisschen unnatürlich. Statt Freude geben sagt man (zumindest in Deutschland) eher Freude machen oder etwas poetischer Freude schenken.

*Freude zu machen und zu bekommen ist das Schönste im Leben*

Freude bekommen klingt allerdings auch noch etwas geholpert, vermutlich weil man *sich freut* und nicht *Freude bekommt*.

Ich würde es wie folgt ausdrücken

> Das Geschenk der Freude zu erhalten und zu geben ist das Schönste im Leben.

Answer (score 1):

Ohne die Originalquelle ist eine Beurteilung kaum möglich, ob es sich um unfreiwillige Komik oder ein Missverständnis des Textes handelt. Meine Hypothese ist, dass der Satz wie folgt lautet:

> Freude, zu nehmen und zu geben, ist das Schönste im Leben.

Das Komma nach "Freude" ergibt ein ganz anderes Textverständnis. Es heißt dann nicht mehr "Freude zu nehmen", sondern "Freude" wird durch den Nebensatz "zu nehmen und zu geben" spezifiziert.

Die Worte "geben" und "nehmen" illustrieren tradtionell das Prinzip der Gegenseitigkeit (vgl. das römische [do ut des](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_ut_des)). Ungewöhnlich ist die Reihenfolge "nehmen und geben" anstatt des üblichen "geben und nehmen". Allerdings bilden die Worte "geben" und "Leben" einen Reim - und das könnte eine Erklärung für die "vertauschte" Reihenfolge sein.

Stilistisch erinnert mich das Ganze an den Werbeklassiker aus den 1950-Jahren

> Wenn einem also Gutes widerfährt, das ist schon einen Asbach Uralt wert.

Answer (score 0):

Von den bisherigen Lösungen gefällt mir das Ersetzen von »nehmen« durch »empfangen« am besten. Alternative:

> Freude zu erfahren und zu geben ist das Schönste im Leben.